# Cast to Integer not working in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table in hive that contains a session_id as a string. It looks something like this: 009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_0 where the integer at following the '_' represents the session number.

I've create a query that splits the string on '_' and then I cast the session number to an integer and do a sort by, however, I'm still getting a results sorted in alphabetical order.

```
select * from (
select session_id, cast(trim(split(session_id, '_')[1]) as int) as rn 
from ttl_session group by session_id, cast(split(session_id, '_')[1] as     int)) a order by session_id, rn
limit 15;
```

Results

```
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_0      0
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_1      1
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_10     10
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_11     11
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_12     12
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_13     13
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_14     14
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_15     15
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_16     16
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_17     17
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_18     18
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_19     19
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_2      2
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_20     20
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_21     21
```

Furthermore, I know hive is at least somewhat treating as an integer since I can add to it e.g.

```
select * from (
select session_id, cast(trim(split(session_id, '_')[1]) as int)+1 as rn 
from ttl_session group by session_id, cast(split(session_id, '_')[1] as int)) a order by session_id, rn
limit 15;


009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_0      1
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_1      2
009ff78f44e2dc69cc022f4530eb69c2_10     11
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

And I soon as I posted it hit me. I needed to trim session_id to be a machine_id before I can sort and order by. DUH!!